# Efficient way of setting bits in verilog

Tags: verilog

I'm just learning verilog and have a question regarding setting bits in a 2 bit register (assuming I'm even making the register correctly).

Suppose I have a hypothetical module, foo(), which has two inputs, and I want to combine these inputs into a 2 bit register. My thinking is that I would do something like ...

```
module foo(a,b)
    input a,b;
    reg [1:0] c;

    c[0] = b;
    c[1] = a;
```

I have two questions:

1. Am I doing it wrong?
2. Is there a better way? (e.g. something like c = {a,b};)

Comment: `assign x = y` is creating a "wire" between `x` and `y`. Pretty efficient.

Comment: Meaning assign c[0] = b; and assign c[1] = a; ?

Comment: Or even `assign c = {a, b}`

Comment: I still need to create the register though right? And what is the difference between 'assign' and 'wire'?

Comment: Depends on what you are trying to do. think of `assign` as a connection *point*, while `wire` is ..well.. wire :)

Comment: Where wire has a delay and electrical characteristics. OK. So is this something I could do when I declare the register, i.e. reg [1:0] c = {a,b}; ?

Comment: I would suggest you to go through some tutorial, play around with code and actually synthesize it and see the resulting RTL schematics. Comments here is not a good place to teach this stuff.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It really depends if you want `c` as a `reg` or a `wire`. Both aproaches work, but `reg` needs to be assigned in procedural block, while `wire` needs an `assign` statement (or assigned at declaration).

As a `reg`, it needs to be defined inside a procedural block. Such as:

```
reg [1:0] c;
always @* begin
  c = {a,b};
end
```

or:

```
reg [1:0] c;
always @* begin
  c[1] = a;
  c[0] = b;
end
```

There is no functional or behavior difference with the two always blocks, it is just a matter of preference for readability.

As a `wire` it can be declared and assigned in one line:

```
wire [1:0] c = {a,b};
```

Or declared and assigned on separate lines:

```
wire [1:0] c;
assign c = {a,b};
```

Or declared with each bit assigned on separate lines:

```
wire [1:0] c;
assign c[0] = b;
assign c[1] = a;
```

All of the above examples will simulate and synthesize the same.

With `wire` if there are two conflicting drivers on the same net, there will be an X in simulation. With `reg` it is last assignment wins in simulation and not synthesis. The `assign` per bit method has more simulation overhead, but normally only noticeable with very large designs.

Simulators are not required to evaluate always blocks at time-0, so there could be a short mismatch. Results will be identical after the stimulus changes after time-0. (Note: SystemVerilog's `always_comb` always does time-0 evaluation and throws errors there is another possible driver on one of its bits it assigns.)

For a small module that only have simple combinational logic; it really doesn't matter using `wire` with `assign` vs `reg` with `always`. With an FSM, I like to put just about all my combination logic in one big `always @*`. I find this typically gives the best simulation performance and synthesis result with my tool set. Occupationally I split the one `always @*` into separate `always @*` chunks when dealing with particularly noise asynchronous input signals.